# PHP preg_replace add tag to digit in string

Tags: php, tags, preg-replace

I have chemical formulas in a database and would like to display them as C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub> instead of C6H12O6. So here is what I was thinking.

```
$formula = preg_replace("(\d)","<sub>?</sub>",$formula);
```

I don't know what to put in place of the question mark.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at: https://www.mathjax.org/ Otherwise I can just say: *delimiters, quantifiers and backreference*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a backreference, like this:

```
$formula = preg_replace('/(\d+)/','<sub>\1</sub>',$formula);
```

I added the `//` as delimiters to make it a proper pattern. I also added a `+` so that it would place all connecting digits in the same `<sub>` tag.